# kinvey fetching and remove not working (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, kinvey

I have this problem with kinvey backend, 
I'm trying to fetch data from my collection but it doesn't work for me. here is my code :

```
var query = new $kinvey.Query();
query.equalTo('_id', '5909e8084c68b1ef74fa4efc');
var dataStore = $kinvey.DataStore.collection('User1Bases', $kinvey.DataStoreType.Network);
var stream = dataStore.find(query);
    stream.subscribe(function onNext(entity) {

        // ...
    }, function onError(error) {
        // ...
    }, function onComplete() {
        //...
    });
```

Can  you help me please

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

If you let run the code you have posted then consider four things:

1. Make sure you have Kinvey implemented:

```js
<script src="https://da189i1jfloii.cloudfront.net/js/kinvey-html5-sdk-3.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

2. Make sure you have initialized the Kinvey service before:

```js
        // Values shown in your Kinvey console
        Kinvey.init({
            appKey: '<your_appKey>',
            appSecret: 'your_appSecret'
        });
```

3. Make sure you are logged in with a user that has the rights to read your collection (should be fine using the All Users role (default)):

```js
 var promise = Kinvey.User.login('<username>', '<password>')
            .then(function() {
              console.log ("You are logged in");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log (error);
            });
```

4. Output the return result to see whats coming back. To make sure you do the query AFTER successful login, paste you query inside the .then function of login. 
   I'm not sure if your query is valid unter 3.x since a lot has changed and I'm not working with older Kinvey versions.

So that all together would look like this:

```js
// Initialize Kinvey 
Kinvey.init({
            appKey: '<your_appKey>',
            appSecret: 'your_appSecret'
        });


// Login with already registered user        
var promise = Kinvey.User.login('<username>', '<password>')
            .then(function() {
              console.log ("You are logged in");
              
              // Your query
              var query = new $kinvey.Query();
           query.equalTo('_id', '5909e8084c68b1ef74fa4efc');
           var dataStore = $kinvey.DataStore.collection('User1Bases', $kinvey.DataStoreType.Network);
           var stream = dataStore.find(query);
           stream.subscribe(function onNext(entity) {
           // Output of returning result
           console.log (entity);

            // ...
        }, function onError(error) {
            // ...
        }, function onComplete() {
            //...
        });
              
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log (error);
            });
```

There are now three return sets possible:

1. Nothing (as you say) -> Something missing/wrong in the code (compare yours with mine)
2. Empty array: Your query didn't find anything, adapt the search value(s)
3. One or more entries in the array -> All fine, what you were looking for!

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is what finally helped me. The key factor was that an authenticated user seems to be required to fetch data from a collection. I was thinking it could be done anonymously (with just the app ID and app secret), but that doesn't seem to be the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When querying by `_id` there is a built in method: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/guides/datastore#FetchingbyId

Try switching to `var stream = dataStore.findById('entity-id');`

Also check to make sure you don't have any preFetch or postFetch BL that is interfering with the query.

Comment: Can you share the syntax you used? I use the above syntax and receive results or errors as appropriate. Do other queries work? Is business logic interfering with your query? You can also try the query from the API console to make sure the request is correctly.